# Box type in R pca2d plot

Tags: r, plot, pca, pca3d

I'm using the `pca3d` package and it's really convenient. However, I'd like to draw a full box around my `pca2d` scores plot, rather than just having an x-axis.

The following code:

```
library(pca3d)
set.seed(111)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol = 100)
gps <- rep(c("Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D"), each=25)
pca <- prcomp(mat)
pca2d(pca, group = gps, legend="topright", bty="o")
```

Gives
[image]

I can't find anything in the documentation for the function and package, although this blogger has managed to do it [here](https://logfc.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/pca3d/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use base (`graphics-package`) R's `box()` command, e.g. like so:

```
box(which = "plot", lty = "solid")
```

[image]